# The meaning and usage of "logo schmogo"

Tags: meaning, social-media, reduplication

I came across the term **"logo schmogo"** and went researching its meaning and usage, and have a vague working-theory, but am still confused. Would be great to learn **the exact meaning and primary usage** of the term. Thanks.

1. I get that this is a form of **reduplication** (repeating a word or adding a second word that sounds similar to the first word) (e.g. easy-peasy, hurly-burly, super-duper) The dictionary gives definitions for some of them, but not this one. Could be that this one is fairly new or still a bit niche.
2. My working theory. I think it's one or a combination of the following, **but I am having a hard time summing it up in a clear sentence**.

- It is used to criticize or mock the "logo is the be-all-and-end-all of branding", or "logo=brand identity" attitude.
- It means "You think your new logo will solve all your problems? You are wrong"
- "Your logo is missing substance, it's just a layer on top."

3. It's harder to take a guess because this term is **mostly used in titles** (for chapters, blog posts), or as an **exclamation** (e.g. Logo schmogo indeed!) or opening of a social media post (e.g. Logo schmogo, blablabla)
4. Here are some use-cases I was able to collect:

- An article titled"School District **Logo Schmogo**:Board Not Happy with the New Emblem and Its Price Tag", an interview in the article says “The idea of a communication plan is much more than an image, a logo,”
- A twitter conversation
  **Political party X** posts: We will put Y first. That is what our new logo will symbolize for everyone.
  **Voter Z** posts: **Logo schmogo**. I'll still never vote for X.
- A blog post with a quote that says:
  "Stuart Elliot of the NY Times summed up the prevailing opinion of design when he once said to me,
  **Logo schmogo**
  Can a logo drive business results?  Absolutely.
  There is one brand that saw a 20% change in their business within 7 weeks of changing their logo and packaging design.
  Yes, that’s right, CHANGE IN LOGO RESULTS IN 20% CHANGE IN SALES IN 7 WEEKS.
  **Logo schmogo indeed!**"
  Then the post goes on explaining that the change in logo resulted in 20% PLUNGE of sales in 7 weeks.
- A blog post titled "**Logo schmogo**", and the first sentence is "A corporate brand is many things to many people. But it isn’t a logo."

4. Related links

- reduplicative: https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/easy-peasy-jiggery-pokery-reduplicative-words
- use-case: https://www.independent.com/2016/07/14/school-district-logo-schmogo/
- use-case: https://narrativebranding.wordpress.com/tag/peter-arnell/

Thanks for taking the time to look into this.

Comment: This really nails it, though I never would have been able to find it on my own. Wow, I learned so much already. I don't know how to thank you. @k1eran Not only is the conversation thread helpful, but the links to the Wikipedia post [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shm-reduplication) and  the paper are unbelievable.[link](https://www.academia.edu/209796/Metalinguistic_shmetalinguistic_The_phonology_of_shm_reduplication)

Comment: No problem @namu. I did feel a bit lousy marking yours as a duplicate as you had obviously put a lot of effort in & had asked a high quality question - hope you stay involved with this site. I randomly read that  "Josephine, Schmosephine" question a few months ago myself and I also found it fascinating!

Comment: @k1eran No worries, writing the question helped organize my thoughts, and I already learned a ton in less than an hour. I've always browsed this site and posted for the first time, and it's such a great experience already. I do have a question, though: can someone still find this question when they search "logo schmogo"? I just hope someone who has a similar question finds their way to the "Josephine, Schmosephine" question, like I did with your help.